# Minecraft - Teleport player on spawn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to teleport the player instantly on spawning. I am aware of the /setworldspawn command. I would like them to spawn into a small building. I cannot make the building larger. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Using scoreboards and the `stat.leavegame` stat, you can detect when a player leaves the game and teleport them to the spawn when they rejoin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the spawn to a larger area elsewhere, then use command blocks to teleport players in that area to your building.